# padding 2D numpy array with 0s

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array of shape (144,X) where X can be any positive integer. I want to pad my numpy array with zeros such that the final shape of my array is (208,5000). How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to [do some research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) before asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible to pad a 2D numpy arrays by passing a tuple of tuples as padding width, which takes the format of `((top, bottom), (left, right))`

example:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
print(A.shape)
```

Output:

```
(2, 4)
```

If I want to make one array shape((5, 9) :

```
B = np.pad(A, (((5-2),0),(7-2,0)), 'constant')
C = np.pad(A, (((5-3),1),(7-4,2)), 'constant')
print(B.shape)  #--->shape((5, 9)
print(C.shape)  #--->shape((5, 9)
```

then:

```
#((top, bottom), (left, right)):
#(144,X) -->(208,5000)
#B = np.pad(A, (((208-144),0),(5000-X,0)), 'constant'): One of the possible modes
```